# Using custom javascript files in React component using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am developing a React application using webpack. For one of my pages (using react-router so it is technically a component) I need to load in two custom scripts. However, I keep getting nosniff error saying that both scripts are being blocked due to non-overlapping MIME-type. I remembered stumbling upon this when I was creating the app in express and that it could be solved by letting the express server use these directories like so:

```html
app.use('/models', express.static(__dirname + '/models'))
app.use('/src', express.static(__dirname + '/src'))
```

I have tried to look into ways of doing this via webpack, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Is there anyone who knows how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have found the solution. Webpack was already serving my public folder, I moved the scripts and their dependencies to the public folder and changed the route to the files and voila!